# Simple ODE function but values explode

Tags: python, math, scipy, differential-equations

guys, I'm trying to run some simple SIR simulations, the idea is to have people adapt to their environment so that if nobody is infected, they interact with 7 others but if the infected population is high they reduce their interaction. This specific variable is b whose evolution I denote by dbdt, but for some reason when I graph it, it is monotonic. When I print dbdt as it is being generated I get the right values, 7,7,7,6,6,5,4,4,7,7, which means that as the epidemic spreads they reduce contact, but as it gets better they increase, but for some reason, the function calculates it and gets ridiculous numbers like 140.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import log, exp
def g(s,t):
    g = 0.2
    k = 1
    N = 100 
    theta = 0.1
    delta = 0.08
    S = s[0]
    I = s[1]
    R = s[2]
    D = s[3]
    C = s[4]
    b = s[5]
    dbdt = b* exp(-k*I/N)
    if dbdt >= 7:
        dbdt = 7
    dSdt = - b*S*I/N 
    dIdt = b*S*I/N - g*I
    dRdt = g*I - theta*R
    dDdt = delta*theta*R 
    dCdt = (1-delta)*theta*R
    return [dSdt, dIdt,dRdt,dDdt,dCdt,dbdt]

#Graph x axis
t = np.linspace(0,20)
#Vector for initial conditions of each equation
s0=[99,1,0,0,0,7]
#Ordinary differential equation
s = odeint(g,s0,t)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t,s[:,0],'r--', linewidth=2.0)
plt.plot(t,s[:,1],'b-', linewidth=2.0)
plt.plot(t,s[:,2],'g-', linewidth=2.0)
plt.plot(t,s[:,3],'y-', linewidth=2.0)
plt.plot(t,s[:,4],'o-', linewidth=2.0)
plt.xlabel("t")
plt.ylabel("Number")
plt.legend(["Susceptible","Infected","Resolving","Dead","Recovered"])

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(t,s[:,5],'m-', linewidth=2.0)
plt.legend(["Distancing"])


plt.show()
```

So the question is: what do I have to fix to make it work properly? Note that the code works if I keep b exogenous.

Comment: `exp(-k*I/N)` is always positive, and, since `I` will eventually approach to 0, `exp(-k*I/N)` will approach 1.  So your DE for `b` will eventually  look like `dbdt = b`.  That's exponential growth.  But then you clip `dbdt` to the value 7.  The equation `dbdt = 7` gives linear growth: `b(t) = 7*t + C`.  So `b` will just continue to grow.

Comment: Ah sorry, that If statement was my failed attempt to stop the problem but yeah it just turned it into a linear function. What would you do to simply have b start at the value 7, decrease as the I/N gets large and then return to 7 when it gets small again? @WarrenWeckesser

Comment: Nevermind got it! Thanks for the help? Should I post the answer here?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import log, exp

beta = 7
def g(s,t):
    g = 0.2
    k = 1
    N = 100
    theta = 0.1
    delta = 0.08
    S = s[0]
    I = s[1]
    R = s[2]
    D = s[3]
    C = s[4]
    #Current value of beta
    b = s[5]
    #New Value of beta
    newbeta = exp(log(beta)-k*I/N)
    #New difference
    dbdt = newbeta - b
    dSdt = - b*S*I/N 
    dIdt = b*S*I/N - g*I
    dRdt = g*I - theta*R
    dDdt = delta*theta*R 
    dCdt = (1-delta)*theta*R
    return [dSdt, dIdt,dRdt,dDdt,dCdt,dbdt]

#Graph x axis
t = np.linspace(0,20)
#Vector for initial conditions of each equation
s0=[99,1,0,0,0,beta]
#Ordinary differential equation
s = odeint(g,s0,t)


f = plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(t,s[:,0],'r--', linewidth=2.0)
plt.plot(t,s[:,1],'b-', linewidth=2.0)
plt.plot(t,s[:,2],'g-', linewidth=2.0)
plt.plot(t,s[:,3],'y-', linewidth=2.0)
plt.plot(t,s[:,4],'o-', linewidth=2.0)
plt.xlabel("t")
plt.ylabel("Number")
plt.legend(["Susceptible","Infected","Resolving","Dead","Recovered"])

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(t,s[:,5],'m-', linewidth=2.0)
plt.legend(["Distancing"])

plt.savefig('simple.png', dpi=1000)
plt.show()
```